# In nodejs, I want to display the files from a directory which is input by the user in the console; How do i bind the user answer to the directory

Tags: node.js, file-handling, readline, readdir

How do i bind the user answer to the directory?
I am getting this error : cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.
I am using readline and readdir.

My index.js code is:

```
const readline = require('readline'); 
const test = './answer/'; const fs = require('fs'); 

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout }); 
rl.question('Enter the name of the source directory? ', (answer) => { // TODO: Log the answer in a database console.log(${answer}); 
fs.readdir(test, (err, files) => { files.forEach(file => { console.log(file); }); }) rl.close(); });
```

Comment: My index.js code is:-

 

    const readline = require('readline');

    const test = './answer/';

    const fs = require('fs');

 

    const rl = readline.createInterface({

    input: process.stdin,

    output: process.stdout

    });

 

    rl.question('Enter the name of the source directory? ', (answer) => {

    // TODO: Log the answer in a database

    console.log(`${answer}`);

 

    fs.readdir(test, (err, files) => {

          files.forEach(file => {

            console.log(file);

          });

        })

 
    rl.close();

    });

Comment: the directory name should be input by the user in the console and files in that directory should be displayed in the console in a serial number order(1,2,3)